# XQuery : how to get distinct values of substrings?

Tags: xml, xquery

My XML file is like this :

```
<element id="1" time="05-08-2012T12:00">...</element>
<element id="2" time="05-08-2012T13:00">...</element>
<element id="3" time="05-08-2012T14:00">...</element>
...
<element id="13" time="06-08-2012T00:00">...</element>
<element id="14" time="06-08-2012T01:00">...</element>
```

Now what I want to do is :

- Create an HTML option box containing only the distinct dates. I tried this :

> for $d in //mesure/@date
>
> for $date in substring($d,0,11)
>
> return distinct-values($date)

But it keeps returning "05-08-2012" as many times as it's printed in the XML file.

- I would also like to know how I can change the value that I put in my HTML option box (for example "05-08-2012" would become "5 August 2012"). Should use a function ?
- Finally, I would like to keep the id of the first element containing a given date so when I choose it in the HTML select box, I can use all the elements from and with this date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
distinct-values(//measure/@date/substring-before(.,'T'))
```

**To get the complete wanted result, use**:

```
  let $months := ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                  'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
    $dates := distinct-values(//measure/@date/substring-before(.,'T'))
 return
    for $date in $dates,
        $d in tokenize($date, '-')[1],
        $m in xs:integer(tokenize($date, '-')[2]),
        $y in tokenize($date, '-')[3]
     return
        ($d, $months[$m], $y, '&#xA;')
```

**The result of applying this XQuery on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <measure id="1" date="05-08-2012T12:00">...</measure>
    <measure id="2" date="05-08-2012T13:00">...</measure>
    <measure id="3" date="05-08-2012T14:00">...</measure>
...
    <measure id="13" date="06-08-2012T00:00">...</measure>
    <measure id="14" date="06-08-2012T01:00">...</measure>
</t>
```

**is**:

```
 05 August 2012 
 06 August 2012
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel when there are already much better abstracted built-in functions: format-date, format-dateTime, etc.?

Comment: @wst, No there aren't. Not in a Recommendation. And these are XPath.30 functions and aren't applicable for a question that is tagged "xquery", but not "xquery-3.0" or "xpath-3.0". Before downvoting all other answers but yours, it is good to have a look at your own answer that offers incomplete hints of non-existing (as standard) functions. Should I mention which of the three answers most deserves the downvote?

Comment: Should you mention or did you already mention? Your ambiguity makes it unclear. Also, OP didn't specify the XQuery version or processor.

Answer (score 1):

That is because if you apply distinct-values to $date, $date alone only has one value (and a single value is always distinct). You need to apply it to the entire sequence, i.e.

```
 distinct-values( for $d in //mesure/@date return  substring($d,0,11) )
```

To change the date, it is probably the best to use the tokenize function to split the components and then reorder them.

```
let $splitDate := tokenize("05-08-2012", "-"), $monthNames := ("January", "February" , ...) 
return concat($splitDate[1] cast as integer, " ", $monthNames[$splitDate[2] cast as integer], " ", $splitDate[3])
```

You could try xs:date(..) to read the date as real date, then use the XQuery date functions to print it, however your input date, has the components in the wrong order, so XQuery can probably not parse it...

Comment: Date parsing functions do exist in the spec.

Comment: Beni, wst has downvoted both you and me -- for not using an XPath 3.0 function ... What do you think about his own attempt at a solution? I already gave him my opinion.

Comment: @wst, No The F & O spec doesn't contain a function named `fn:format-dateTime` -- it is only in the WD (working draft) for F&O 3.0. And it isn't easily applicable to values that aren-t valid xs:date representations.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev These functions are already implemented in most if not all major XQuery processors. And much easier to coax his time vals into xs:dates than to go through all that parsing.

Comment: @wst: Where does the spec has date parsing functions? They are nowhere to be found. (xs:date("06-08-2012")` won't work.)

Comment: As @DimitreNovatchev verbosely points out, they are part of the XQY3 Working Draft, which is not yet a recommendation. However, BaseX, eXist, MarkLogic and others already implement them.

Comment: @wst: But where? I have actually looked at that before posting my answer and could not find any.

Comment: Are you looking for the W3C draft? It's the XPath functions doc that you want...http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-format-dateTime

Comment: @wst: But that is date *formatting*. Where is the date *parsing*? Without parsing there is nothing to format...

Comment: Right, no parsing in the spec. In this case it would be a pretty trivial regex: `replace('05-08-2012T12:00','^(\d\d-\d\d)-(\d{4,4})(T\d\d:\d\d)$','$2-$1$3:00-08:00')`

Comment: @wst: Well if you have to use replace anyways, you can just as well use tokenize...

Comment: @wst, If you call this "pretty trivial regex" ..., the tokenization should be "super-simplistic" :) And for 3 hours you were telling us about some alleged "date-parsing" functions in the WD, until you found out that there weren't such...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Actually no I wasn't; it's pretty obvious I thought BeniBela was asking about formatting functions. But it's cute that you're so dramatic about it :) Your tokenization code is 6 lines. My regex plus a call to a format function is 2. Since you're "super-smart" maybe you can figure out which one is better ;)

Comment: @wst: In your first comment to my answer, you were talking about parsing... My tokenize/format call is also only 2 lines. (And it even removes the leading zero as in Robin's example)

Comment: @wst, Of course, I can put the tokenization logic on one line, but I value readability and understandability -- unlike the RegEx you provided.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev It's just as readable if you understand regex, as with anything else. And you can put an entire anything on one line - doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: @wst, You regex is *minimally* readable. When I write complex Regexes I split them into multiple lines and intersperse the RegEx with comments. Like here: http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?revision=1.11&view=markup&sortby=file  (line 236 to line 255) is the lexer for JSON.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Sounds like you need to brush up on your regex ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to get distinct-values on the sequence:

```
distinct-values(//mesure/@date/substring(.,0,11))
```

Dates can be formatted using [`fn:format-dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-format-dateTime) on the xs:dateTime value:

```
format-dateTime($d, "[D] [MNn] [Y]")
=> 5 August 2012
```

For your final question, you will need to be more specific about what you want to do with IDs on these elements, and provide more information about this data. (This should probably be a separate question)

Comment: Offering to use a function that is only available in XQuery 3.0 (F & O 3.0), which is still not a w3C Recommendation -- is not a good advice. As the OP hasn't tagged this as "xslt-3.0" or "xpath-3.0", he probably isn't interested in (or can't use) XQuery 3.0. Neither are you offering a good advice with this, nor are you providing a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: Not to mention that the offered XPath 3.0 function only accepts an `xs:date` as its first argument, which none of the distinct values are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I'm using only XQuery 1/2 so I can't use format-dateTime. But I'm going to keep this idea in mind.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev format-dateTime accepts xs:dateTime. There are 2 complementary functions for xs:date and xs:dateTime.

Comment: @wst, The values in the problem are neither of these.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm not going to explain how much easier it would be to coax his values into valid xs:dateTimes. One line of code.

Comment: @wst, The OP has explained to you that XQuery 3.0 is out of the question. I hope that now you understand the appropriateness of an XQuery 3.0-based answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I hope you understand that it is very likely the OP already has this or a similar function available in his XQY implementation, regardless of whether it technically supports the WD.

Comment: @IanThompson, that's correct, and at this point, it's pretty likely. In the event that it's not, there are two other answers to choose from.